# How can one turn a malleable encryption to not malleable

Tags: encryption, homomorphic-encryption, malleability

An encryption algorithm is "malleable" if it is possible to transform a ciphertext into another ciphertext which decrypts to a related plaintext. That is, given an encryption of a plaintext m, it is possible to generate another ciphertext which decrypts to f(m), for a known function f, without necessarily knowing or learning m.

And non-malleable is the adversary shouldn't be able to come up with a ciphertext whose underlying plaintext is related to the original message through a relation that also takes public keys into account.

My question is how can one turn a malleable encryption scheme into one that is not
malleable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like you are asking about converting an IND-CPA encryption scheme into an IND-CCA one.

- In the symmetric-key setting, the standard approach that works is [Encrypt-then-MAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption#Encrypt-then-MAC_(EtM)).
- In the public-key setting, this is a longstanding open question. There is no known black-box construction of IND-CCA from IND-CPA, nor is there a known impossibility of such a construction. However, there is such a transformation in the random oracle model: the [Fujisaki-Okamoto transformation](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-48405-1_34).